Question pertaining to properties of limits.
I was doing some calculus and came across the following question.
Find $\lim_{h\to 0} \theta$ where $ \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x+\theta h)$
Solving the problem using the Taylor Polynomial expansion of $f$ about $x$ up to two terms is quite easy and yields the result  $\theta = \frac{1}{2}$. However, I go wrong somewhere when we take an example, say $f = e^x$, and try to evaluate the limit.
$lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{x+h} - e^x}{h} = lim_{h \to 0}e^{x + \theta h} $
Now, if we divide both sides of the limit by $e^x$ we get,
$lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h} - 1}{h} = lim_{h \to 0}e^{\theta h} $
The LHS evaluates to $1$ and for this to be true, $\theta$ can be any real number in $(-\infty, \infty)$. Clearly, dividing both sides of the limit has caused us to lose to some information about the limit. Why is this the case?

Are you sure you want $f'(x+\theta h)$ and not $f'(x) + \theta h$? The latter measures the error using the derivative to approximate the difference quotient.

As long as $\theta$ lies between $0$ and $1$, this equation just represents Langrange's Mean Value Theorem. However, $\theta = 1/2$ as we take the limit. That's what I understood.

I think I understand the question. See my answer.

I think you misinterpreted the question. Under certain conditions on $f$ and the defining equation for $\theta$ $$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)} {h} =f'(x+\theta h) \tag{1}$$ we get $\lim_{h\to 0}\theta=1/2$. Note that the defining equation $(1)$ shows that $\theta$ is a function of $x, h$ but the limit is taken with respect to $h$ and hence $x$ is to be treated as constant.
For your example $f(x) = e^x$ we have $$\frac{e^h-1}{h}=e^{\theta h} $$ ie $$\theta=\frac{1}{h}\log\frac{e^h-1}{h}$$ and you have to evaluate limit of right hand expression as $h\to 0$ and you can confirm that the answer is $1/2$.
What you have done in your post is similar to evaluating limit of $y=\frac{\sin x} {x} $ and noting that $y$ is bounded and $xy=\sin x$ and then taking limits as $x\to 0$ to get $0=0$.

Thanks, that clears things up quite a bit!

The information that you  lose when you divide by $e^x$ is that $\theta$ is a function of both $x$ and $h$.
-

$\theta$ does depend on $x$ but in the current context $x$ is treated as a constant and limiting variable is $h$.
